# Retrieving the next smallest element of a Python set

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

The [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is a reasonably fast method of generating primes up to a limit `k` as follows:

1. Begin with the set `p = (2, 3, 4, ..., k)` and `i = 2`.
2. Starting from `i^2`, remove all multiples of `i` from `p`.
3. Repeat for the next smallest `i` in `p`, until `i >= sqrt(k)`.

My current implementation looks like this (with the obvious optimisation of pre-filtering all the even numbers):

```
# Compute all prime numbers less than k using the Sieve of Eratosthenes
def sieve(k):
    s = set(range(3, k, 2))
    s.add(2)

    for i in range(3, int(sqrt(k)), 2):
        if i in s:
            for j in range(i ** 2, k, i * 2):
                s.discard(j)

    return sorted(s)
```

**EDIT:** Here is the equivalent `list` based code:

```
def sieve_list(k):
    s = [True] * k
    s[0] = s[1] = False
    for i in range(4, k, 2):
        s[i] = False

    for i in range(3, int(sqrt(k)) + 2, 2):
        if s[i]:            
            for j in range(i ** 2, k, i * 2):
                s[j] = False

    return [2] + [ i for i in range(3, k, 2) if s[i] ]
```

This works, but is not entirely correct. The lines:

```
for i in range(3, int(sqrt(k)), 2):
    if i in s:
        [...]
```

Find the next smallest element of `s` by testing set membership for every odd number. Ideally the implementation should actually be:

```
while i < sqrt(k):
    [...]
    i = next smallest element in s
```

However, since `set` is unordered, I do not know how (or even if it is possible) to get the next smallest element in a more efficient way. I have considered using a `list` with `True`/`False` flags for primes, but you still have to walk the `list` looking for the next `True` element. You can't just actually remove elements from the `list` either, as this makes efficiently removing composite numbers in step 2 impossible.

Is there a way to find the next smallest element more efficiently? If not, is there some other data structure that allows `O(1)` removal by value and an efficient way to find the next smallest element?

Comment: p.s. if you're using Python 2.x, use `xrange` to avoid creating a list every time.

Comment: If you analyze your algorithm, it's actually pretty efficient. You only do O(n) `if i in s` calls. The rest of your algorithm is at least O(n) because you have to construct the list and delete O(n) elements from it. Thus, the "inefficient" way you find the minimum doesn't affect the order of your algorithm's running time.

Comment: `O(sqrt(n))` calls actually, so now that I think about it it probably costs almost nothing compared to the rest of the process. Also I realise there is nothing I can do to improve the asymptotic complexity, I was just looking for some small % improvement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sets are unordered because they are internally implemented as a hashset. There's no efficient way to find the minimum element in such a data structure; `min(s)` would be the most Pythonic way to do so (but it is O(n)).

You can use a `collections.deque` *along with* your set. Use the `deque` to store the list of elements in sorted order. Every time you need to get the minimum, pop elements off the `deque` until you find one that is in your set. This has amortized O(1) cost across your entire input array (since you only have to pop n times).

I should also point out that there can be *no* data structure that has O(n) creation from a list (or O(1) insertion), O(1) removal by value and O(1) minimum-finding; such a data structure could be used to trivially implement O(n) general sorting, which is (information-theoretic) impossible. The hashset gets pretty close, but has to sacrifice efficient minimum-finding.

Comment: Good point about it being impossible, when you put it in terms of sorting it is so obvious! I'm not sure how a `deque` buys me anything over just walking through the odd numbers and doing `if i in s`, though. Isn't hashset membership effectively O(1) anyway?

Comment: Yes, it is. In your case, I think you are already as efficient as you reasonably need to be. A deque would help if you were removing elements at random.

Comment: Thanks. Interestingly the list version is faster, even if you just return the set without sorting it (4sec vs 7.5sec for `k` = 30M). I expected the set to be faster.

Comment: `set.discard` is slower than `list[i] = False`, and that's the hot loop in your code (because `set.discard` requires hashing, bucket lookup, possible set resize, etc., and `list[i]` is just a list indexing operation). Similarly, `if i in set` is slower than `if list[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a set you can use a list. Initialize the list with None for unmarked. You can use the element index as the number.

1. Initialize the list
2. Start with p = 2
3. Mark all multiples of `p` in the list with 'M' for marked
4. Find the next unmarked element in the list and make that the new `p`. If there is none, you are done.

If you need to find the next unmarked index, you can simply look at the elements that come after index `p` and are equal to None.

Comment: I already mentioned using a `list` in the question. The issue with a `list` is that it is indexed by position not value, so you cannot efficiently remove non-primes in step 2.

Comment: My apologies, I did not read closely enough. I think you want to avoid marking non-primes several times. Do you think removing the non-primes from the set will make the algorithm faster?

Comment: I initially implemented this using `list` (see edit) but ran into the same problem--you still have to iterate every odd number to find the next prime. I can't see any way around this using `list` or `set`.